# Krakend community edition don't follow redirect

Tags: java, krakend

is it possible to ask Krakend(version 1.3) community edition not follow redirect.

I know it is possible for Enterprise edtion.
https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/backends/client-redirect/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible out of the box

Comment: Thanks @alo , so only solution will be to buy enterprise. right?

Comment: Well, this is an open source project. It means that you can clone the project and add the functionality you want. But if you want this done in the software without coding anything, then yes, the enterprise solution gives you that